# Automate tasks in Oracle11g

Tags: automation, oracle11g

I am creating a database for an auction in which I have a table that stores the entries of Items that are put up for auction.

```
create table items(
item_ID number(5) PRIMARY KEY,
SDate DATE NOT NULL,
EDate DATE NOT NULL, //end date for auction
minBid number(5,2) NOT NULL,
bidInc number(2,2) NOT NULL,
title varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
descr varchar2(255),
currentBid number(5,2)
)
```

Now after the end date has passed I want the database to automatically delete that entry from the table.
How do I do it?

Comment: I did some snooping around and i guess DBMS_SCHEDULER is what i am looking for...so can someone explain that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could write a job in the Database what will delete rows older than X time, but since you tagged this as C# I'm guessing you want it done in your auction application.

In that case, you could create a `Timer` that will run a `DELETE FROM items WHERE EDate > XXX` query every time it runs.

EDIT: In that case, you can define a Stored Procedure that will delete old rows, and then you'll need to schedule it with a `DBMS_JOB`. I don't have an Oracle DB at hand to test this, but you could try running this:

Create a stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure delete_old_auctions
as
begin
    delete from items where edate < sysdate
end;
```

Then you need to create a job that will execute this stored procedure every X time.

```
dbms_job.submit(
    what=>'your_db.delete_old_auctions',
    next_date=>sysdate+1/24,    -- start next hour
    interval=>'sysdate+1/24');  -- Run every hour
```

Comment: No, i want the database itself to handle this and not my application.Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: In that case, I updated the answer. Unfortunately I'm unable to test this right now, but even if it doesn't work from the first try, you should have something to go on.

Answer (score 2):

All those people who are stuck in a similar solution here's how you do it.

step 1:create procedure

```
create procedure item_delete as
begin
delete from items where edate<sysdate
end;
```

step 2:automate using DBMS_SCHEDULER

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
job_name        => 'delete_old_items',
job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
job_action      => 'exec item_delete',
start_date      => sysdate,
repeat_interval => 'freq=daily; byhour=0;byminute=0;bysecond=0;',
end_date        => NULL,
enabled         => TRUE
);
END;
```

references
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#i1000363